# Adding filtering to an Array element

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to add an excel sheet with a range to a VBA array and apply filtering to it. I am then printing it as a picture to PowerPoint. How can I apply Range.AutoFilter method within the MyRangeArray array?

```
'Create a New Presentation
Set myPresentation = PowerPointApp.ActivePresentation

'List of PPT Slides to Paste to
MySlideArray = Array(2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)

'List of Excel Ranges to Copy from
    MyRangeArray = Array(Sheet1.Range("A6:P28"), _
    Sheet4.Range("B6:P17"), _
    Sheet6.Range("B6:P16"), _
    Sheet9.Range("C6:P15"), _
    Sheet11.Range("B6:P14"), _
    Sheet16.Range("B6:P14"))

'Loop through Array data
 For x = LBound(MySlideArray) To UBound(MySlideArray)
   'Copy Excel Range
      MyRangeArray(x).CopyPicture

 'Paste to PowerPoint and position
  On Error Resume Next
    Set shp = myPresentation.Slides(MySlideArray(x)).Shapes.PasteSpecial
  On Error GoTo 0

  With myPresentation.PageSetup
  'Lock Aspect Ratio
    shp.LockAspectRatio = msoTrue

  'Assign Height Width
    shp.Height = 11.16 * 28.3465
    shp.Width = 23.88 * 28.3465

  'Assign Position
    shp.Left = 0.75 * 28.3465
    shp.Top = 2.7 * 28.3465 ' 28.3465 points=1cm         
  End With    
Next x
```

I expect the filter to be applied to a selected range of cells in a selected Sheet.

Comment: What have you tried so far?   When you say filter, how?

Comment: Just apply the [Range.AutoFilter method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.autofilter) to your range `MyRangeArray(x).AutoFilter(…)` before you `MyRangeArray(x).CopyPicture` should work.

Comment: I was trying something like Sheet1.Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="abcd" but don't know the syntax to use it properly within the array

Comment: @Pᴇʜ I want to apply the filter to particular sheets

Comment: @MEnum Your question is very unclear. I linked the documentation, you can get the correct syntax there. Then just apply the filter to the desired sheet. I don't get where your actual issue is. Please be much more specific in asking. Explain it in your original question if possible (comments are commonly too short).

Comment: @Pᴇʜ actually I want to apply the Range.AutoFilter method within the MyRangeArray array to each sheet separately. How can I do that?

Comment: As I already said: `MyRangeArray(x).AutoFilter(…)` for example `MyRangeArray(0).AutoFilter(…)` then is the same as `Sheet1.Range("A6:P28").AutoFilter(…)`